# Condition for the roots of $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_n=0$ not all to be real

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> Show that the roots of the polynomial equation $$x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_n=0$$ cannot be all real if $(n-1){a_1}^{2}-2na_2\lt0$
>
> The inequality was wrongly written before it has been changed now.

---

**My attempt:-**

**Attempt 1:-**

First I tried differentiating the the function $f(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_n$ to get

$$\begin{aligned}
f'(x) &= nx^{n-1}+(n-1)a_1x^{n-2}+(n-2)a_2x^{n-3}+\ldots+a_{n-1}\\
&= \dfrac{n}{x}(f(x))-(a_1x^{n-2}+a_2x^{n-3}+\ldots+na_{n-1})-\dfrac{na_n}{x}
\end{aligned}$$

I was thinking that if I could prove that the no of distinct roots of $f'(x)$ are less than $\left \lfloor{\dfrac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor$, then all the roots of $f(x)=0$ are not real. But I couldn't figure out how to manipulate $f'(x)$ so as to arrive at the condition that the question asks to prove or for that matter how to prove that the no. of roots of $f'(x)$ are less than $\left \lfloor{\dfrac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor$.

**Attempt 2:-**

I thought that why not start messing around with the expression that we are needed to prove $\lt0$, i.e. $(n-1){a_1}^{2}-2na_2$.

$a_1=-\sum{\alpha} \qquad\qquad a_2=\sum{\alpha\beta}$

So, $$(n-1){a_1}^{2}-2na_2=(n-1)\left(\sum\alpha\right)^2-2n\left(\sum{\alpha\beta}\right)=n\sum{\alpha^2}-\left(\sum{\alpha}\right)^2$$

I don't know how to arrive at the required condition from the point that I reached in this attempt.

> Can you push me in the right direction by giving a hint as to what should be my line of thought while attempting the problem

Comment: Is each $a_i$ given to be real?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan - Though it is not given in the statement of the problem but the author has told to consider all the coefficients as real until told otherwise.

Comment: What is the source of this formula please?

Comment: @NoChance Which formula?

Comment: What is the source of the test formula $(n-1)a_1^2-2na_2<0$. Thank you.

Comment: @NoChance The question asks to prove the expression is $<0$. So, I guess the question is the source of the formula. I am not sure I got your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $n$ reals $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$. By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$(1.\alpha_1+\dots+1.\alpha_n)^2\le (1^2+\dots+1^2)(\alpha_1^2+\dots+\alpha_n^2)$$
so
$$\left(\sum \alpha_i\right)^2\le n\sum \alpha_i^2$$
What you proved with your second try is that for your polynomial, this inequality doesn't stand. So the hypothesis must be wrong, and not all $\alpha_i$ are real.

You were close :-)

Comment: I was wondering if you could answer my question for @Dominik below please. Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

The inequality should be in the other direction, i.e. the roots cannot be all real if $(n - 1)a_1^2 - 2na_2 < 0$. For example, the equation $x^2 - 3x + 2$ has the two real solutions $x = 1$ and $x = 2$, but $1 \cdot 3^2 - 2\cdot2\cdot2 = 1 > 0$.

Your second attempt leads to the solution.

Let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ denote the roots of the polynomial (according to their multiplicity). Then $a_1 = -\sum \limits_{i} \alpha_i$ and $a_2 = \sum \limits_{i < j} \alpha_i \alpha_j$. Now if all $\alpha_i$ are real, then by Jensen's inequality

$$\left( \sum \limits_{i} \alpha_i\right)^2 = n^2 \left( \sum \limits_i\frac{1}{n} \alpha_i\right)^2 \le n^2 \sum \limits_i \frac{1}{n} \alpha_i^2 = n \sum \limits_{i} \alpha_i^2$$
holds, but this means
$$(n - 1)a_1^2 - 2n a_2 = n \sum_i \alpha_i^2 - \left(\sum \limits_i \alpha_i\right)^2 \ge 0.$$

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me apply the rule to: $f(x)=x^4-3x^2+x-1$. In this case the left hand side of the rule is $(4-1).(1^2) - ((2*4)*(-3))=3+24=27$. Now $27 > 0$, yet $f(x)$ has $2$ complex roots. What I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance : in your example, $a_1=0$, not $1$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, you are correct, I should get $(4-1)(0)^2-((2*4)(-3))=+24>0$. Still I am not sure how it agrees with the OP claim. Thank you.

Comment: @NoChance: the OP says that $(n-1)a_1^2-2na_2<0$ is a sufficient condition for not all roots being real, not a necessary condition. For example, the constant coefficient $a_n$ can change the number of real roots, and has nothing to do with this condition.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, thank you much for following up. I guess this test is good for answering "Are all roots complex?".